# How do I link data from an Access query into Excel?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a large amount of data that I want Access to query and not bring everything into Excel.

How do I save the query from Access so that Excel will recognize it as an external source?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a query directly in Access and save it there. If the database is set as an ODBC connection In Excel you can choose DATA> Import External Data> New Database Query> select the database from the list and then the query you saved.

Alternately there are other ways to create the query, but if you are familiar with Access this is a pretty easy way to get the data.

Or are you asking how to store the query itself outside of the Access database as well?